# What technology is being used to change URL without changing page?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, clean-urls

So i was browing through some news article and came across this 
    http://www.theonion.com/article/84-million-new-yorkers-suddenly-realize-new-york-c-18003

Its not the article im interested at this point,  it is actually how they achieve the sorcery with the URL changing as you scroll down the page.

Do they just create clean URL's (via rewrite or whatever method) and have an external library just reflect it in the url as you scroll to it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: makes allot more sense now